# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/all/search_tracks failed, reason: socket hang up

Tags: node.js

```
(node:1691) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/all/search_tracks failed, reason: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/logileap/Desktop/musiczen/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1455:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:1691) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1691) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My query is:
var searchData = await fetch(mainURL+'/all/search_tracks',optionsForSearch)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: You should write your query/code and also format it.